# customized xkb layouts not working (in KDE?) after upgrade from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, kubuntu, xkb

I customised my keyboard layout in 9.10 by editing the appropriate `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` file. After upgrading to 10.04 I noticed it had overwritten all my modifications, so I recovered the layout and overwrote the symbol file's `base` entry.

Sadly KDE (and, presumably, the entire OS) seems to ignore the files altogether. The help files don't mention anything about modifying layouts anyway (and the layout switcher seems to be using `setxkbmap`, which uses the above path according to its `man` page), so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Do I need to compile this into some other format somehow or how do I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried to edit manually the xorg.conf file?

Answer (score 2):

The X server stores compiled keyboard layouts in `/var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`. Deleting them should force recompilation.